# Why is using tinyxml2-ex::text returning corrupted text?

Tags: visual-c++, tinyxml2

I am trying to use the [`tinyxml2-ex`](https://github.com/stanthomas/tinyxml2-ex) library to read some XML data.

When I try using it's specific API call:

```
const CString strNameToUse(tinyxml2::text(pAssign).c_str());
```

The resulting string loses things like accents. In the end I have reverted to my original approach with the UTF8 handling:

```
const CString strNameToUse(CA2CT(pAssign->GetText(), CP_UTF8));
```

This works fine. Does anyone know why the `tinyxml2-ex::text` approach fails? Note that it is permissible to the use the `tinyxml2` namespace.

---

The referred to library is using `std::string` and does it like this:

```
// helper function to get element text as a string, blank if none
inline std::string text (const XMLElement * element)
{
    if (!element)
        throw XmlException ("null element"s);

    if (auto value = element -> GetText())
        return std::string (value);
    else
        return ""s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library author explained (GitHub [discussion](https://github.com/stanthomas/tinyxml2-ex/issues/7#issuecomment-1174395112):

> It's because `tixml2ex::text` (see line 465 in `tixml2ex.h`) does this:

```
if (auto value = element -> GetText())
    return std::string (value);
```

> which will corrupt any string containing characters outside ASCII 127.